# software for detecting voices on audio recording

Tags: sound, vlc

I record audio for hours on my smartphone for security purposes, personal safety in shared accommodations, and need to prepare evidence but it takes forever to listen to these recordings.  VLC really is terrible for this as even the play faster, slower are hidden in the  menus.  What I want is a player that skips the no-voice or "silent" ie. irrelevant parts of recordings and stops when it detects human voices or other anomaly sounds like loud crashes and bangs.  Then I can take over from there, listen and make note of the times when voices and sounds to be used as evidence.  Is there anything like this?
I saw this Python: https://gist.github.com/analyticsindiamagazine/c1ebc56e2dece9629e7c67e5406281e8#file-comparingsongs-ipynb
but for the record I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Gnome desktop.

Comment: Btw, you can enable shortcuts for VLC play speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Audacity

Not really what you want but it has some features that may help. For such advanced feature, you may look for similar audio editing tools.

1. Open file > Select track
2. Analyze > Label sounds ...
3. Set threshold measurement and level then press OK
4. New track created with labels.

You can play one by one, delete trivial labels then File > Export rest as list if you want. Below an example with (-20dB Peak) and exported list.

[image: screenshot of example]

```
0.250567    4.830930    Sound 01
8.469161    12.778912   Sound 02
18.401633   25.688118   Sound 03
27.963265   33.826531   Sound 04
37.033787   42.425986   Sound 05
45.663311   54.793968   Sound 06
57.369796   64.856735   Sound 07
69.156463   89.201814   Sound 08
```